# Displaying a section of a HTML page in another HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, splunk

I want to display a particular section of very large HTML page (say, "page1.html") through another HTML page (say, "page2.html"), which will contain the links to every section of page1.html. How can I achieve this using simple javascript, jquery, etc. page1.html is actually being rendered through splunk and page2.html is a normal html page that has links to various sections of page1.html. Can this be achieved?

Sorry, couldn't provide pictures as my reputation is below 10.

Let me clarify. There are a range of applications(over 100) on different servers. each application contains a master page like page1.html. There is a search box in page2.html where I type in or select the application whose statistics I want to view.
The sections refer to particular statistics I want to view, suppose I want view only server statistics on which the app is running, then I will click on a link or button (on page2.html) that will take me to that section of the master page (i.e., page1.html) where the relevant information is shown. Similarly if I want to see the application statistics I will click on a link or button (on page2.html) that will take me to that section of the master page where the application statistics are being displayed.

**Here is the code for page2.html:**

```
<body class="simplexml preload locale-en">

<a class="navSkip" href="#navSkip" tabindex="1">Screen reader users, click here to skip the navigation bar</a>
<div class="header splunk-header">
    <div id="placeholder-splunk-bar">
        <a href="{{SPLUNKWEB_URL_PREFIX}}/app/launcher/home" class="brand" title="splunk &gt; listen to your data">splunk<strong>&gt;</strong></a>
    </div>
        <div id="placeholder-app-bar"></div>
</div>
<a id="navSkip"></a>
<div class="dashboard-body container-fluid main-section-body" data-role="main">
<div class="dashboard-header clearfix">
    <h2>Application Dashboard HTML</h2>
</div>
<div class="fieldset">
    <div class="input input-text" id="input1">
        <label>Application</label>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="row1" class="dashboard-row dashboard-row1">
    <div id="panel1" class="dashboard-cell" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="dashboard-panel clearfix">

            <div class="panel-element-row">
                <div id="element1" class="dashboard-element html" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="panel-body html">
                            <center><h1 class="golden_gradient">$tok_application$ Application Status Dashboard</h1></center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="row2" class="dashboard-row dashboard-row2">
    <div id="panel2" class="dashboard-cell" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="dashboard-panel clearfix">

            <div class="panel-element-row">
                <div id="element2" class="dashboard-element html" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="panel-body html">
                            <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%">
                                        <pre><a style="text-decoration: none" onclick="loadURL()"><font size="4"><p align="center"><b>Website Availability</b></p></font></a></pre>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="50%">
                                        <pre><a style="text-decoration: none" onclick="loadDBStat()"><font size="4"><p align="center"><b>Database Availability</b></p></font></a></pre>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%">
                                        <pre><a style="text-decoration: none" onclick="loadBM()"><font size="4"><p align="center"><b>Batch Jobs</b></p></font></a></pre>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="50%">
                                        <pre><a style="text-decoration: none" onclick="loadIT()"><font size="4"><p align="center"><b>Infrastructure Dashboard</b></p></font></a></pre>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%">
                                        <pre><a style="text-decoration: none" onclick="loadBusiness()"><font size="4"><p align="center"><b>Business Dashboard</b></p></font></a></pre>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="50%">
                                        <pre><a style="text-decoration: none" onclick="loadCMRegression()"><font size="4"><p align="center"><b>Capacity Management Regression</b></p></font></a></pre>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I want the section of the master page to printed inside

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Also I am a newbie, so please kindly provide a little detailed explaination. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want a good answer, you must first learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) an appropriate question

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of page1.html and just put it on page2.html?

Comment: Or copy the html code from page1.html and then add it to page2.html, I'm not quite sure what your looking for.

Comment: cannot provide screenshots as page1.html displays real time statistics for a range of applications.

Comment: could you please provide an example of each page?

Comment: If you don't want to duplicate your content you'll need to go through your server language. I don't know anything about splunk, but this is usually done in PHP or ASP depends of your server technology.

Comment: `iframe` or `frameset` will help you.

Comment: You could send the data over to the other page using the methods `get` or `post` using html code.

Comment: It looks like Splunk is a proprietary thing you probably cannot modify directly, so it may not even be possible to do what you are explaining. Some code from "page2.html" would be helpful. Also, if you can't provide screenshots on SO, host them externally and supply a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp has a method using iframes to display a web link.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300px" src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>

<p>When the target of a link matches the name of an iframe, the link will open in the iframe.</p>
```

[code taken from w3scools.com]